# How to "Torify" requests to one specific web address

Tags: configuration, torsocks, ip-address, torify

i would like to "Torify" requests from my computer to a specific web address. This web address is providing an API and I want to use information from this API using the Tor network.

I have already tried `torify`, but that only allows me to select an application to "Torify" and I basically want any request to the address to go trough Tor, not only from one application.

Is this possible and what would be the approach?

Comment: Ok, found something that seems to work for me.. Chrome add on called "Browse with Onion".

Comment: Could you please describe your solution? So it can help future users.